# How to set up image view so that image fill the whole size and doesn't stretch in Swift?

Tags: swift, imageview, contentmode

I want to show 4 imageViews on my screen. The images should `always fill` the whole image view area. The problem is, that I don't know how to fix that without stretching the photo.
I've tried nearly everything but nothing really seems to work. Even if I set the `contentMode`, it doesn't work.

If I set the contentMode to `scaleAspectFit`, it looks like that:

[scaleAspectFit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mY2mK.png)

If I set it to `scaleAspectFill`, it looks terrible and if I set the `contentMode` to `scaleToFill`, it looks like that:

http://i65.tinypic.com/6fxxzt.jpg

Anyway, do you know how to combine these 2 images, so that the whole size is filled and the image isn't stretched?

Comment: try this: imageView.contentMode = scaleAspectFill; imageView.clipsToBounds = true

Comment: Can you show the image of expected output?